# How to get custom HTML markup with <s:radio> Struts 2 tag

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, themes

Following is `<s:radio>` tag i'm using to print list `listOfOptions` as list of options

```
<s:radio cssClass="checkbox" listKey="id" listValue="text" name="mylist" list="listOfOptions" value="optionId" />
```

Following html markup gets generated:

```
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox" value="1" id="MyForm_mylist1" name="mylist">
  <label for="MyForm_mylist1">
    First Option
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox" value="2" id="MyForm_mylist2" name="mylist">
  <label for="MyForm_Mylist2">
    Second Option
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox" value="3" id="MyForm_mylist3" name="mylist">
  <label for="MyForm_mylist3">
   Third Option
  </label>
```

Can I generate HTML markup somehow which wraps every input and label elements in `div` with different class names.

I'm using `simple` theme type.

Comment: Thanks guys, but i guess no easy solution to this other than making own struts theme. For now i have done some css tricks to achieve what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to control the HTML output of your Struts2 Tags is to create your own theme if you are not happy with the themes provided by Struts2.

See the [Struts2 Themes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2+Themes) section in the Wiki.

Comment: I know of that option, but it's lengthy process for small needed output. I was thinking there must b some other way, like by using attributes values of struts tags etc..anyways, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sure the benefit of using an own theme has only an effect if you are using this kind of form controls more then once in your app. But in this case you can also simple use plain html tags in combination with s:iterator and s:property tag.

Comment: using iterator makes difference in processing time? just asking

Comment: @Eez: The iteration happens in either way.

Answer (score 0):

The `css_xhtml` theme wraps each form element and label with `div` if the `labelposition` of the element is `top`, which is default.

The `div` has class `wwctrl`, that is hardcoded.

To specify element class and label class use `cssClass`. See the theme `header` code for [`css_xhtml` theme](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/css-xhtml-theme.html) in the documentation page.

Comment: It doesn't wraps each label and input element, it wraps all in one div if we use css_xhtml. i tried.

Comment: it wraps *all* elements?

Comment: @Eez What a class have those div?